# Slow WMI request on Windows 2008R2

Tags: wmi

Has anyone got any suggestions to speed up this WMI query? I'm updating a client application every 5 seconds to show the CPU stats. It was much quicker on Windows 2003 but takes at least 5 seconds to return an integer for 4 CPU cores:

```
Private Sub GetProcessorIdleTime(ByVal Server As String) 

        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("\\" & Server & "\root\CIMV2", "SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor")
        Dim collection As ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()

        For Each row In collection
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & Convert.ToInt32(row("LoadPercentage"))
        Next

End Sub
```

Or is there a better way to retrive this information remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the performance, you must re-use the WMI connection to the remote server, establishing a connection is one of the more expensive tasks when you execute a WQL sentence. 
In your code you are setting a new WMI remote connection each time. So rewrite your code creating a new method to establish the remote connection and then reuse (share) the `ManagementObjectSearcher` object in your GetProcessorIdleTime method.